# idea: getting locations nearby

Tags: geolocation, distance

currently, i have a table with locations (latitude, longitude). I calculate nearby calculations using sin, cos as described [here](http://labs.qandidate.com/blog/2014/09/09/having-fun-with-geometry-data-in-mariadb-and-elasticsearch/)

This seems rather slow. I am having the idea of pre-calculating the distance to a fixed point f and store it along the locations. When I now want to find locations nearby i just calculate distance to the same fix point and can then find them by doing some less or equal comparing.

Does my idea make sense? Is there a standard way to do that? I am in the thinking phase, so i do not have any code to show yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea won't work unless all your locations are collinear, which most probably is not the case.

Are you using SQL to do the calculations? Are you properly using indexes? Maybe you could share a bit of your code with us.

Comment: yes, it is sql. i do not have code yet, i am just in the thinking phase

Comment: How big is your locations table? What does "rather slow" mean for you?